# Is it possible to create muti thread in a flask server?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, threadpoolexecutor, flask-restx

I am using `flask` and `flask-restx` try to create a protocol to get a specific string from another service. I am trying to figure out a way to run the function in server in different threads. Here's my code sample:

```
from flask_restx import Api,fields,Resource
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parent = api.model('Parent', {
    'name': fields.String(get_answer(a,b)),
    'class': fields.String(discriminator=True)
})
@api.route('/language')
class Language(Resource):
    # @api.marshal_with(data_stream_request)
    @api.marshal_with(parent)
    @api.response(403, "Unauthorized")
    def get(self):

        return {"happy": "good"}
```

What I expect:

In Client side, first the server should run, i.e., we should able to make `curl -i localhost:8080` work. Then when a specific condition is true, the client side should receive a GET request with the parent JSON data I have in server. However, if that condition is true, the GET request should not be able to return the correct result.

What I did:

One of the method I used is wrap up the decorator and `Class Language(Resource)` part in a different function and wrong that function in a different thread, and put that thread under a condition check. Not sure if that's the right way to do.I was seeing anyone said `celery` might be a good choice but not sure if that can work in `flask-restx`.

Comment: I suspect that gunicorn can be potentially helpful. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/deploying/gunicorn/

Comment: Yeah, but how to include gunicorn on the client side? Looks like gunicorn can be used by bash command instead in a python script.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for you. to run a process in the background with flask, schedule it to run using another process using APScheduler. A very simple package that helps you schedule tasks to run functions at an interval, in your case one time at utcnow().

here is the link to [Flask-APScheduler](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-APScheduler/).

```
job = scheduler.add_job(myfunc, 'interval', minutes=2)
```

In your case use 'date' instead of 'interval' and specify run_date

```
job = scheduler.add_job(myfunc, 'date', run_date=datetime.utcnow())
```

You can send arguments to the function:

```
job = scheduler.add_job(myfunc, 'date', args = (your args), run_date=datetime.utcnow())
```

here is the documentation:
[User Guide](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's a definitely good point. One of the concerns to me is in my case above, you may notice I am wrapping up my func in a class - `class Language(Resource):`. I know APScheduler works for func but not sure if it also works for a class.


Also, I think date will allow me to run the code at a specific date instead under a specific condition. Is there a way to run the func when a specific condition equals to true?

Comment: You can specify the condition in the function or you can schedule the job only if the condition is true. Concerning the class, you can  schedule to run a static or class method .  I edited the question to make it a bit clearer.